# .NET Core 3.1 Serve static Files

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-staticfile

I have an app in .Net Core 3.1 and Angular 10.

In my Startup.cs, I have the folowing code:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
 {
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath,"Pictures")),
  RequestPath = new PathString("/Pictures") 
 });
```

The files are saved into the correct path but when I want to display them from web with the path:

http://mywebsite/Pictures/pic.jpg, I just get a:

[image]

without errors, no 404 or 401.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: `The files are saved into the correct path` what does that mean? Are the files stored in `wwwroot/Pictures` ? You wouldn't need to use the second `UseStaticFiles` then.

Comment: `without errors, no 404 or 401.` did you check the browser's Developer Tools? Images are loaded separately from the page itself so a 404 for an image won't cause the entire page to fail.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I removed UseStaticFiles() and got the same result.
No errors also in developer's tools.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

In my controller I wrote an absolute path:
C:...

I changed to environment.ContentRootPath and it works.

Thanks for the answers.